# merging two partitions on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning

This is how my partitions look like in Ubuntu. I would like to merge two partitions /dev/sda8 and /dev/sda/7 because I am unable to use both of them.

```
/dev/sda8       111G  2.7G  103G   3% /
udev            1.9G   12K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           763M  864K  762M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.9G  252K  1.9G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   72K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda7       117G   52M  111G   1% /home
```

Please let me know if there is any way to do it. And all the partitions looks ugly..I would like to have only one partition which would be my home folder.

Answer (score 1):

While it is a good practice since forever to keep user homes on a separate partition, lately this single filesystem has become a trend I see. probably because of big disks.

Anyway, you can "merge" the partitions. First you need to get rid of /home mount. means you need to log-off all non-root sessions and open a root one. then create a /home.tmp or something and

```
cp -a /home/* /home.tmp
```

to copy the /home content into it. then

```
umount /home
```

if its says the fs is busy, check

```
lsof -n | grep home
```

and kill any process still using it. now swap the home.tmp and home. I have no idea if ubuntu still uses /etc/fstab, but I assume it does. remove the /home mount from there. now you can re-login or even reboot and use gui tools to try and

**oh my... why is / partition AFTER the /home ???????** What did the installer's author smoke to allow it?

sorry dude, scratch the above. you cant "grow" partitions backwards. you need to move things. The only way to do that is with an  unmounted / fs. means you need a livecd or something. to boot and manipulate the partition table off-line.

Feel adventurous? While it is doable, most probably you will end-up reinstalling that precious ubuntu. Chances are you still have little if none customizations on it so you can just start it all over choosing the partitioning scheme suits you best.

Comment: Partitioning is not the same thing as choosing a a partitioning scheme. Partitioning scheme is a term that should be reserved for partition table structures.

Comment: If you can't explain it simply, you don't understand it well enough. And what's with the bolded line with seven question marks?

Answer (score 0):

Ugly partitions? Well, sometimes when you look under the hood, it isn't very neat, but that's Linux for you.

You are using both / and /home, trust me.

Having a separate /home partition is useful, for it makes backup very quick. If you decide later on to change OS, all you have to take with you is the /home partition.